# One Certificate for Multiple Provisioning Profile?

Tags: ios, certificate

I have successfully build an ipa with one app(for development), but somehow after creating different project and build another new ipa I can't install the app directly into my device, it's installing then after it finishes it just gone suddenly. So I am wondering if this is caused by one certificate only for multiple provisioning profile?

Answer (score 1):

Its due to same **Bundle Id** and **Provisioning Profile** profile. Create different/unique **Bundle Id** for different project and **Provisioning Profile** also.

For more information please visit [Apple's Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html)